# Problem with NGINX, Kubernetes and CloudFlare

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am experiencing exactly this issue: [Nginx-ingress-controller fails to start after AKS upgrade to v1.22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908774/nginx-ingress-controller-fails-to-start-after-aks-upgrade-to-v1-22), with the exception that none of the proposed solutions is working for my case.

I am running a Kubernetes Cluster on Oracle Cloud and I accidentally upgraded the cluster and now I cannot connect anymore to the services through nginx-controller. After reading the official [nginx documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/), I am aware of the new version of nginx, so I checked the documentation and re-installed the nginx-controller following [Oracle Cloud official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengsettingupingresscontroller.htm).

I am able to perform step by step as I run:
`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`

And then an `ingress-nginx` namespace is created and a LoadBalancer is created. Then as in the guide I have created a simple hello application (though not running on port 80):

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-hello-world
  labels:
    app: docker-hello-world
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-hello-world
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-hello-world
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: docker-hello-world
        image: scottsbaldwin/docker-hello-world:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8088
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: docker-hello-world-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: docker-hello-world
  ports:
    - port: 8088
      targetPort: 8088
  type: ClusterIP
```

and then the ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: docker-hello-world-svc
              port:
                number: 8088
```

But when running the curl commands I only get a `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

So I then tried to connect to some python microservices that are already running by simply editing the ingress, but whatever I do I get the same error message. And when setting the host as the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ing
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: ANY_MICROSERVICE_RUNNING_IN_CLUSTER
              port:
                number: EXPOSED_PORT_BY_MICROSERVICE
```

Then, by setting the subdomain on CloudFlare I only get a 520 Bad Gateway.

Can you help me find what is that I do not see?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to your Ingress resource.

In Kubernetes versions v1.19 and above, [Ingress resources should use ingressClassName instead of the older annotation syntax](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource). Additional information on what should be done when upgrading can be found on the [official Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation).

However, with the changes it requires at face value, from the information you're provided so far, your Ingress resource should look this:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ing
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: docker-hello-world-svc
            port:
              number: 8088
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.com
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Additionally, please provide the deployment Nginx-ingress logs if you still have issues, as the Cloudflare error does not detail what could be wrong apart from providing a starting point.

As someone who uses Cloudflare and Nginx, there are multiple reasons why you're receiving a 520 error, so it'd be better if we could reduce the scope of what could be the main issue. Let me know if you have any questions.