# ingress-nginx-controller CrashLoopBackOff because of deprecated API's used

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have been getting alerts that a few APIs were deprecated in v1.22 of Kubernetes cluster in GCP and so I changed all of my deployments and nginx controllers to version apps/v1 and networking.k8s.io/v1 . But my cluster still shows that there are some components using the deprecated api's.
The error on the pod is -

```
k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.6/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource
```

The deprecated apis called are -
API :

```
/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/ingresses
```

for user agent -

```
nginx-ingress-controller/v0.35.0 (linux/amd64) ingress-nginx/54ad65e32bcab32791ab18531a838d1c0f0811ef
```

and

```
/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/ingressclasses
```

for

```
nginx-ingress-controller/v0.35.0 (linux/amd64) ingress-nginx/54ad65e32bcab32791ab18531a838d1c0f0811ef
```

Today some of deployments were unable to reach from the browser, what changes do I need to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the issue is that the **NGINX Controller has to be compatible with the kubernetes version**.

**Follow resolutions steps below :**

1. Check the version of NGINX.
2. Check Kubernetes version GKE console in GCP UI.
3. Confirm the supported versions with kubernetes [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx#support-versions-table).
4. Update NGINX (change the API version of NGINX Ingress)

**If NGINX was installed using Helm, its name will be ingress-nginx, and it can be upgraded using a helm command like below:**

```
helm upgrade --reuse-values ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

You can also refer to the GCP official doc [Upgrading third-party components](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#ingress-v122) and similar [Github issue](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/7264) for relevant info, which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Also refer to similar **Rychu's** [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908774/nginx-ingress-controller-fails-to-start-after-aks-upgrade-to-v1-22) answer.